How to Programmatically Log In to Azure Using SDKs or API Calls Without Azure CLI?
I’m looking for a way to programmatically log in to Azure without needing to install the Azure CLI. Currently, I use the following commands:
az login --service-principal -u <user_credentials> -p <password> --tenant <tenant_id>
az account set -s <subscription_id>

However, these require the Azure CLI to be pre-installed. Is there an alternative method to authenticate with the same credentials (service principal, tenant, subscription ID) in Python without relying on the Azure CLI? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Have you tried any script so far? @Timmy Suntichaiwakin

Have you tried installing Azure CLI and do you need any insights on it? @Timmy Suntichaiwakin

For programmatically logging in and acquiring tokens in Python, the package you would want to use is azure-identity.
Since you are using a Service Principal for logging in, you would want to use ClientSecretCredential to create a credential object which you would use later on with other Azure SDKs to authorize requests.
Here's some sample code:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


   credential = ClientSecretCredential(
       tenant_id="<tenant_id>",
       client_id="<client_id>",
       client_secret="<client_secret>",
   )

from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient
queue_service = QueueServiceClient(account_url="https://account.queue.core.windows.net", credential= credential)
# Do some operations on queues now


You can use clientId, clientSecret to get access_token, then request azure rest api with the access_token, which case azure cli installation is not required. Even many azure-related modules do not need to be installed, using the primitive method
import requests
import json

clientId = ''
clientSecret = ''
tenantId = ''
subscriptionId = ''

token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/'

def get_access_token():
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': clientId,
        'client_secret': clientSecret,
        'scope': 'https://management.azure.com/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()['access_token']

def get_azure_resource(url: str):
    access_token = get_access_token()
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

try:
    resource_url = f'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}?api-version=2022-12-01'

    resource_info = get_azure_resource(resource_url)

    print(json.dumps(resource_info, indent=4))
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print(f'HTTP Error: {e}')
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f'Request Exception: {e}')


I would suggest that you check the following libraries and their documentation:

https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-resource/
https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md

They also come with code samples for different tasks.
